# Setting horizontal spanning in Windows 7

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

Is there any tool/option/thing which allows two monitors in Win7 to act like big one?

I need to get two projectors together to make bigger resolution. I am currently using Win7 64b Professional SP1 and my GPU is ATI FirePro V4800. I have all rights on this PC so any advanced modification is not a problem.

I am talking about [topic discussed on answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/when-will-horizontal-span-return-to-windows-wddm/ee1a4777-eba2-4ed8-8421-2a8d8005066f). Microsoft employee is talking about some software:

*Horizontal spanning is not a supported feature in Windows 7, natively. However there are some third-party software to accomplish the same.*

Can you recommend me something? I can't use eyefinity and I can't change OS.

Comment: Have you looked at / installed ATI's drivers, and used their Display tool?

Comment: Yes, I haven't found any option like that. I am more interested in any 3rd party software, but I don't even know if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

It is called an "extended desktop" and is performed by the graphics card/chip and software installed. You may need to upgrade your graphics card to get this feature.

In W7 the selection in Graphics Properties would be "Extend these Displays"

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Move-windows-between-multiple-monitors

http://www.microsoft.com/athome/organization/twomonitors.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this isn't a comment about the above answer, but I just joined and can't comment on others' answers yet.

I assume he's not talking about "extended desktop" functionality, as he mentions eyefinity.  I believe he's looking for something that would allow his OS to treat 2 monitors of equal resolution (e.g. 1680x1050) as one large (3360x1050) display, rather than having windows see them as two distinct displays.

It would help if we knew what your system specs are, especially your video card model, your Windows 7 version, and what level of permissions you have on your system (e.g. "Administrator," "Power User," etc.).

Edit: In light of your response below..
Sorry I'm a couple of months too late, but look into ATI Hydravision - not sure if the FirePro supports it, but most new Radeon cards do.

Comment: That's exactly what I am talking about **Isochronous**.

I need to get two projectors together to make bigger resolution. I am currently using Win7 64b Professional SP1 and my GPU is ATI FirePro V4800. I have all rights on this PC so any advanced modification is not a problem.

I have found on AMD website that eyefinity is not supported by 4800 card. Is there any software/hardware which I could use?